# How to install gem with additional configuration using bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, rubygems, bundler

I am implementing a [geolocation library](https://github.com/ry/geoip-city) that requires the following gem installation

```
sudo gem install geoip_city -- --with-geoip-dir=/opt/GeoIP
```

I'm unsure of how I can add this to my `Gemfile`.

When I push/deploy on my production server, how can I link the gem to the geoip lib there as well?

If it makes a difference, I could probably use `./configure --prefix=/path/to/my_app/lib/` so that the C lib was installed directly inside my Rails 3 app. Or would this be advised against?

Answer (score 1):

From about 3/4 of the way down [this page on the Bundler website](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html):

> If you really need to pass flags to a C extension, you can use the bundle config command:
>
> $ bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
>
> Bundler will store this configuration in ~/.bundle/config, and bundler will use the configuration for any bundle install performed by the same user. As a result, once you specify the necessary build flags for a gem, you can successfully install that gem as many times as necessary.

Comment: hmm... this is helpful, but it doesn't really help me when my code gets pushed to my production server as the user is not going to be same. Is there anyway to commit these bundle configs in my repo and have bundler use them?